# Better way to fix mocha lcov output using sed

Tags: sed, mocha.js, jscoverage

Due to the know prob of mocha-lcov-mocha breaking file paths, I need to fix the current output paths that looks like this:

```
SF:Vis/test-Guid.coffee
SF:Vis/Guid.coffee
SF:Vis/test-Vis-Edge.coffee
SF:Vis/Vis-Edge.coffee
```

into

```
SF:test/Vis/test-Guid.coffee
SF:src/Vis/Guid.coffee
SF:test/Vis/test-Vis-Edge.coffee
SF:src/Vis/Vis-Edge.coffee
```

I'm not very good with sed, but I got it to work using:

```
mocha -R mocha-lcov-reporter _coverage/test --recursive | sed 's,SF:,SF:src/,' | sed s',SF.*test.*,SF:test//&,' | sed s',/SF:,,' | sed s',test/src,test,' | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js
```

which is basically doing 4 sed commands in sequence

```
sed 's,SF:,SF:src/,' 
sed s',SF.*test.*,SF:test//&,'
sed s',/SF:,,' 
sed s',test/src,test,'
```

my question is if there is a way to do with this one sed command, or use another osx/linux command line tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially put "src/" after every ":" and then if "test" is found on the line replace "src" with "test":

```
$ sed 's,:,:src/,;/test/s,src,test,' file
SF:test/Vis/test-Guid.coffee
SF:src/Vis/Guid.coffee
SF:test/Vis/test-Vis-Edge.coffee
SF:src/Vis/Vis-Edge.coffee
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks it worked great (here is the commit with the fix https://github.com/TeamMentor/node-teammentor/commit/c7e3df53ca4bd161d01e01e792cc13f17ea45ccb). I had to make a small change to ```sed 's,SF:,SF:src/,;/test/s,src,test,'``` in order to not affect other coverage lines that used a colon ':'

Answer (score 0):

You *could* put all the sed commands in a file, one line per command, and just use "sed -e *script*".  But if you just want it on a single command-line, separate with semicolons.  This works for me:

```
sed 's,SF:,SF:src/,;s,SF.*test.*,SF:test//&,;s,SF:,,;s,test/src/,test,'
```

Answer (score 0):

sed command

```
 sed '\#test#!{s#SF:Vis/#SF:src/Vis/#g};\#SF:Vis/test#{s#SF:Vis/test#SF:test/Vis/test#g};' my_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
awk -F: '/SF/ {$0=$1FS (/test/?"test/":"src/")$2}1' file
SF:test/Vis/test-Guid.coffee
SF:src/Vis/Guid.coffee
SF:test/Vis/test-Vis-Edge.coffee
SF:src/Vis/Vis-Edge.coffee
```

---

How it works:

```
awk -F: '                               # Set field separator to ":"
/SF/{                                   # Does line start with "SF"?
    $0=$1FS (/test/?"test/":"src/")$2   # Recreat String by adding "test" if line contains "test", else "src"
    }
1                                       # Print all lines
' file                                  # read the file
```